# linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -vto see invocation) Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native

I Working on React Native project and I have issues(warnings & error) build the app on Xcode[image]

Any Clues what's the problem or Maybe solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate symbol issues as shown in the Linking. The program has no idea about which one it should call among those duplicated symbols.

When we try using different libraries at the same time, there are duplicated symbols for functions included from the shared header.

There are few approaches/changes in header or Libraries you can make:

1. **Use Macros instead of functions** as Macros are only textual substitution so no symbol generation
2. **Make functions inline**,  Same logic as Macro. The function body are injected directly into each place the function is called
3. **Using static** to make functions local in each file. Statics are local and hence are not shared among files.